# Vbscript - Multiple lines on vbs script email

Tags: email, vbscript, multiline

I use the following code to send automatic emails, passing a parameter in them :

```
Const schema   = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
Const cdoBasic = 2
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2
Dim oMsg, oConf
Dim sDateTimeStamp

Set args = WScript.Arguments
arg1 = args.Item(0)  


' E-mail properties
Set oMsg      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
oMsg.From     = "test@gmail.com"  ' or "Sender Name <from@gmail.com>"
oMsg.To       = "test2@gmail.com"    ' or "Recipient Name <to@gmail.com>"
oMsg.Subject  = "Subject"
oMsg.TextBody = "Transfer of files failed - Check RUNLOG for error.  Julian date :  " & arg1  


' GMail SMTP server configuration and authentication info
 Set oConf = oMsg.Configuration
 oConf.Fields(schema & "smtpserver")       = "smtp server" 'server address
 oConf.Fields(schema & "smtpserverport")   = 25              'port number
 oConf.Fields(schema & "sendusing")        = cdoSendUsingPort
 oConf.Fields(schema & "smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic         'authentication type
 oConf.Fields(schema & "smtpusessl")       = False             'use SSL encryption
 oConf.Fields(schema & "sendusername")     = "test3@gmail.com" 'sender username
 oConf.Fields(schema & "sendpassword")     = "password"      'sender password
 oConf.Fields.Update()
```

I would like to add a multiline string in the text message body, i have tried using the _ concat operator like so :

```
multi = "aaaaaa " & _
   "FROM NC301B " & _
   "WHERE EDIPROC like 'P30_' " & _
   "AND (LF301M > 0) "
```

but it does not work. Can someone give me pointers? Thank you.

I would like the end body of the email to contain this:

```
"Transfer of files failed - Check RUNLOG for error."  
"Julian date : " & arg1  
"Line of text"  
"Line of text"
```

If this is also doable without multi-lining with `& _` then i m curious about that also. Thank you!

Comment: If it's a `.TextBody` just place a hardcoded newline `vbNewLine`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding a string concatenation character doesn't automatically insert a newline, you need to use one of the built in constants to define a newline

```vb
multi = "aaaaaa " & vbNewLine & _
   "FROM NC301B " & vbNewLine & _
   "WHERE EDIPROC like 'P30_' " & vbNewLine & _
   "AND (LF301M > 0) "
```

---

`vbNewLine` is the best one as it's platform specific. But for completeness the other ones are;

```vb
'--- Named Constants ---
vbCr              'Carriage Return
vbLf              'Linefeed
vbCrLf            'Carriage Return Linefeed

'--- Character Codes using Chr() ---
Chr(13)           'Carriage Return
Chr(10)           'Linefeed
Chr(13) & Chr(10) 'Carriage Return Linefeed
```

---

If you also wanted to build a `HTMLBody` for your e-mail using newline would not work as HTML ignores whitespace, you would need to use `<br />` to force a newline.